# getmeasuredheight return 0 or same when use ReplacementSpan

Tags: java, android

ShadowSpan.java

```
public class ShadowSpan extends ReplacementSpan {
public ShadowSpan(int color, PointF offset){
}
@Override
public int getSize(@NonNull Paint paint, CharSequence text, int start, int end, @Nullable Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    return (int)paint.measureText(text,start,end);
}

@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text, int start, int end, float x, int top, int y, int bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawText(text,start,end,x,y,paint);
}}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String tx = "sssss3333";
    SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(tx);
    ShadowSpan ss = new ShadowSpan(Color.GRAY,new PointF(8,8));
    AbsoluteSizeSpan as = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(100);
    sp.setSpan(ss,0,tx.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    sp.setSpan(as,0,tx.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(sp, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    tv.measure(0,0);
    int h = tv.getMeasuredHeight();
    int w = tv.getMeasuredWidth();
    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    fl.addView(tv);
}}
```

The above is all my code, very simple, but there is a very strange problem.

if I use ReplacementSpan, and if the debug is a real machine, then getMeasuredHeight will only return 0 or the same value, if the debug is virtual Device, then getMeasuredHeight will return the correct value.

However, whether it is a real machine or a virtual device, the value returned by getMeasuredWidth is correct.

This is the build environment:
compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 27

the real machine is sangsumg Galaxy Note 9

Update:
I have some new discoveries, even on virtual devices, if you use API27, there will be problems, API28 is no problem, the real machine API is 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the TextLine.java source code, because ReplacementSpan is inherited from MetricAffectingSpan, and Text is processed in the process of processing MetricAffectingSpan and then dealing with CharactorStyle, and when MetricAffectingSpan is ReplacementSpan, then directly draw and continue, the following CharactorStyle is not processed at all